# Passing user ID to an applet?

Tags: java, php, applet

I have a Java applet running on a Drupal site:

```
<Applet Code="Go.class" codebase = "/java" width=200 Height=100 />
```

The problem is that I need to pass in the person's user ID to the application. However, if I do it like this:

```
<Applet Code="Go.class" codebase = "/java" width=200 Height=100>
    <param name="userid" id="parm" value="5">
</applet>
```

Then you can imagine how easy it would be for any user to mimic another user. So how can I get access to the user's id in the applet?

Right now, the only way I can think of is perhaps saving this in session and someone figuring out how to access the same session via the applet. But I don't even know if that is possible?

Comment: Your applet is going to have to authenticate the user, probably by requiring not only a username but a password (entered by the user).

Comment: Would it not work to have a folder where I store the user ID as /id/SESSION_ID , and then have Java connect to the server to get the file and read the value in there as the ID? I can maybe pass the session ID through as the parameter? But then people can still guess the key?

Answer (score 0):

Given that want to show the user their own data, its a fair assumption that the application has **already authenticated the user**, and that the server knows who the user is.

You can use the session id, but remember to generate a **random session id** on the fly, each time a new user gets authenticated. Use that session id in the applet param, to map back to the user.